# Regex: beginning of line?

Tags: regex, match

I was wondering if my expression here can  match the word cat or Cat only at the beginning of a line and if this also means that **if there is a new line, it will also match**, it is not just at the beginning of the entire chunk of text/string.

ex:

cat and

Cat

would highlight both instances at the beginning of the two lines

```
/^\b([Cc]at)\b/g
```

My other, separate, question is, how do you match, let's say, 'cat', anywhere except for at the beginning of a line? How do you negate the beginning of line, but include all other instances?

ex:

```
cat likes cat and himself.
```

would only match the second mentioning of the word cat.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need the multiline flag and ignoreCase flag can also be used to make your regex to

```
/^cat\b/gmi
```

as far as your optional question is concerned, if your regex supports lookbehind, then it would be

```
/(?<=.)cat/
```

if not

```
/.(cat)/
```

and take the Group 1.